# What is the general view on using Staging tables? We use them a lot for Order imports from External vendors

Tags: c#, plsql, soa

We have been having a lot of internal debate regarding staging tables.  Some are view staging tables as archaic and will prevent the ability to build re-usable services, etc.  It is also being communicated that these will prohibit the business to grow and handle expanded business channels.

I am not necessarily for or against either option, but I do know that having the staged data has been a life saver in many occasions and has made it really easy to re-import orders we have had issues with.

Just wanted to see what others thought about staging data and what other methods are being used to handle scenarios similar to ours (Taking orders from external partners, Amazon, etc and importing them into our ERP system).

Thanks,

S

Comment: I think this is a good topic, though I reckon it is more suitable as a community wiki considering the subjective nature.

Comment: +1-Never seen "Hi Gurus", as an intro on SO before.

Comment: If having staged data correctly solves your problem, why would you change?

Comment: Mitch....that is exactly what we have been trying to communicate, but you know how it goes with mgmt.

Comment: "staging tables will prohibit the business to grow and handle expanded business channels" is just FUD to try to prop up a weak argument. Perhaps they think the staging tables are the cause of performance issues? The question should be "how do staging tables prohibit our growth?" Also, how do they think moving to a more SOA-ish solution (sans staging tables) might improve the situation?

Comment: They are saying that by building loosely coupled services it will make it easier to implement and maintain new partners that we may want to add.  One of the other Devs and I find the term "re-use" and loosely coupled to be inappropriately being used.  It is also a way to say we are not onboard with the "vision" of the business. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some places I've worked I've used staging tables, others I've used other techniques.
Each one has its own advantages and disadvantages.
That said, don't worry about it.
If some data feed comes along that requires some method other than what you are doing, then you'll come up with a new solution.
Change is driven by requirements.

(personally, when someone comes to me and says "We have to change to X because what we do now is inefficient and bad and witches will come and eat our children", they have this image in their minds that on tuesday, we will have an opportunity to triple our client base but only if we do this new thing, but if we don't get cracking on it now, then we'll miss the opportunity because none of those potential clients is willing to wait even a minute and they'll all demand the exact same thing and we can build exactly what they want right now even though we have no idea what they want HURRY HURRY HURRY AND DON'T BREAK ANYTHING.  Which, of course, isn't how anything works.  A single client (or whatever) comes along and says "Hey, we want your services, can you accept our XML?" to which the response is always "Sure thing", and then you get tasked with it and can make intelligent decisions, and plan things out.  As opposed to the "chicken with its head cut-off" methodology preferred by people who like technical words but hate knowing anything tehcnical)

Comment: (or was I venting too much there?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for a debate - you have a working system.  Anyone who thinks their "re-usable services" theory can do it better should put up or shut up.

Let them build a test implementation on your development servers for a common high volume scenario, and compare it to the current system - including criteria for recovery and re-import after a failure.

I hear this all the time where I work as well (usually from managers who just read an article about SOA and XML) and in situations dealing with large amounts of data - bulk imports into staging tables can handle a much higher data volume than any type of web service.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  Basically the people that don't have to manage the errors are the ones that are pushing for the change.  Can't tell ya how many times we heard "won't change and will never happen".

Comment: What you posted is almost identical to what we are going through.  Our director (was previously an accountant) bought Oracle SOA and is now trying to justify by having Oracle Architects come in and say the way we currently process is not business of the future and we are doing things the old/archaic way.  Bare in mind we have about 125 employees....so as I am sure you can imagine any data load, etc barely even touches our Oracle DBs.